# If my adapter says 1A or 2.1 which port should I use for my iPod nano?

Tags: ipod

If my wall adapter says 1A and 2.1 A. Which one should I use for my IPod nano?

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't actually matter.
The iPod will require 1A, but as Amps are "pulled" by the deive rather than being "pushed" by the socket, the end result is the same whichever you plug it into.

You will only notice a difference if you plug in an iPad which needs 2A. If it can only pull 1A it will charge more slowly.

Comment: I agree that it is unlikely to matter for the iPod Nano which charger is used.  In my experience iPads will charge very slowly with  a 1A charger, quite noticeably so compared to 2A chargers.  Most iPhones will have a less significant difference in charging rates from 1A to 2A.  I suspect that all iPods, except recent Touch models, are only capable of 1A charging so even if plugged into a 2A charger it will charge at only 1A rate.  Either charger is safe to use so don't let that concern you.